# Django - Dynamically create element

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am making a complete admin and invoice app in Django.

For the invoice app, as the user clicks on "Create Sales Invoice" the invoice screen appears.

Now I want the system to dynamically generate new bill as soon as this screen appears, but not saved. As the user starts entering item, I want a new item detail (i.e. each bill has one item detail which has the list of items, its quantity and price).

However, none of them shall be saved unless the user clicks on create bill button.

I need help in how to do this thing, ie create a bill and item detail as the user goes to a create bill, link these two with foreign key, but also have the option to discard them if the user does not end up on clicking "save" button.

**Edit 1**

My invoicing HTML:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block title %}

{% load static from staticfiles %}
<script src="{% static 'bill/script.js' %}"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bill/style.css' %}">

<title>Sales Invoice</title>

{% endblock %}



{% block content%}
<invoice>
<div id="invoice">
<invoiceheader>
    <!--
    <h1>Invoice</h1>
    <address>
        <p>Jonathan Neal</p>
        <p>101 E. Chapman Ave<br>Orange, CA 92866</p>
        <p>(800) 555-1234</p>
    </address>
    <span><img alt="" src="logo.png"><input type="file" accept="image/*"></span>
-->
</invoiceheader>
<invoicearticle>
    <!--<h1>Recipient</h1>-->
    <code>
        <p>Customer code: 
            <input id="customer-code" ></input></p>
    </code>
    <address>
        <p></p>
        <p id="companyname">Some Company</p>
        <p id = "companyaddress">c/o Some Guy</p>
    </address>
    <table class="meta">
        <tr>
            <th><span>Invoice #</span></th>
            <td><span>101138</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><span>Date</span></th>
            <td><span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><span>Amount Due</span></th>
            <td><span id="prefix">Rs. </span><span>600.00</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="inventory" id="inventory_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="1"><span>Item Code</span></th>
                <th colspan="2"><span>Item Name</span></th>
                <th colspan="1"><span>Unit Rate</span></th>
                <th colspan="1"><span>Discount 1</span></th>
                <th colspan="1"><span>Quantity</span></th>
                <th colspan="1"><span>Discount 2</span></th>
                <th colspan="1"><span>Free Quantity</span></th>
                <th colspan="1"><span>VAT Type</span></th>
                <th colspan="1"><span>VAT</span></th>
                <th colspan="1"><span>Net Rate</span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <form>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1"><a class="cut">-</a><span class="itemcode"  contenteditable></span></td>
                <td colspan="2"><span contenteditable></span></td>
                <td colspan="1"><span contenteditable>150.00</span></td>
                <td colspan="1"><span contenteditable></span></td>
                <td colspan="1"><span contenteditable>4</span></td>
                <td colspan="1"><span contenteditable></span></td>
                <td colspan="1"><span contenteditable></span></td>
                <td colspan="1"><span contenteditable></span></td>
                <td colspan="1"><span contenteditable></span></td>
                <td colspan="1"><span contenteditable></span></td>
            </tr>           
        </tbody>
        </form>
    </table>
    <a class="add">+</a>
    <table class="balance">
        <tr>
            <th><span>Total</span></th>
            <td><span data-prefix></span><span>600.00</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><span>Amount Paid</span></th>
            <td><span data-prefix></span><span>0.00</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><span>Balance Due</span></th>
            <td><span data-prefix></span><span>600.00</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</article>

</div>
</invoice>


<script type="text/javascript">
/*  url_sellbill = '{% url "billbrain:sellbill" %}'   */
    csrf_token='{{csrf_token}}'

</script>


{% endblock %}
```

My related jquery file (only the necessary part):

Generating Table:

```
function generateTableRow() {
var emptyColumn = document.createElement('tr');



emptyColumn.innerHTML = '<td><a class="cut">-</a><span class="itemcode" contenteditable></span></td>' +
    '<td colspan="2"><span contenteditable></span></td>' +
    '<td><span contenteditable>100.00</span></td>' +
    '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>' +
    '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>'+
    '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>' +
    '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>'+
    '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>' +
    '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>' +
    '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>' ;


return emptyColumn;
}
```

Adding customer details on user entering customer code:

```
$( "#customer-code" ).change(function() {

/*alert( "Handler for .change() called." );*/
var input = $("#customer-code").val();
(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "", 
        type : "POST", 
        data : { customer_code: input,
                 datatype: 'customer',
                 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf_token}, // data sent with the post request
        dataType: 'json',

                // handle a successful response
        success : function(jsondata) {
            $('#companyname').html(jsondata['name'])
            $('#companyaddress').html(jsondata['address'])
            console.log(jsondata); // log the returned json to the console
            console.log("success"); // another sanity check
        },


        });
  }());

});
```

Similarly, for products, on user entering product id, the other details are auto-generated:

```
  $("#inventory_table").on("focus", ".itemcode", function(){
    $(this).data("initialText", $(this).html());
    /*alert( "On focus for table inventory called." );*/
    });

$("#inventory_table").on("blur", ".itemcode", function(){
/*alert( "On blur for table inventory called." );*/
var input = $(this).html();

if ($(this).data("initialText") !== $(this).html()) {

    var el = this;
    /*valueis='Hi 5'
    alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(4) span').html());*/
    (function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "", 
            type : "POST", 
            data : { item_code: input,
                     datatype: 'item',
                     'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf_token}, // data sent with the post request
            dataType: 'json',

                // handle a successful response
            success : function(jsondata) {  
                $(el).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2) span').html(jsondata['name'])
                $(el).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2) span').html(jsondata['name'])
                $(el).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(3) span').html(jsondata['sellingprice'])

                console.log(jsondata); // log the returned json to the console
                alert(jsondata['name']);
                console.log("success"); // another sanity check
            },

        });
    }());
  }
});
```

Finally, this is my views.py file's relevant function:

```
def bill(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    datatype = request.POST.get('datatype')
    if (datatype == 'customer'):
        customerkey = request.POST.get('customer_code')
        response_data = {}
        response_data['name'] = Customer.object.get(customer_key__iexact=customerkey).name
        response_data['address'] = Customer.object.get(customer_key__iexact=customerkey).address
        jsondata = json.dumps(response_data)
        return HttpResponse(jsondata)

    if (datatype == 'item'):
        productkey = request.POST.get('item_code')
        response_data = {}
        response_data['name'] = Product.object.get(prodkey__iexact=productkey).name
        response_data['sellingprice'] = float(Product.object.get(prodkey__iexact=productkey).selling_price)
        #response_data['address'] = Product.object.get(prodkey__iexact=productkey).address
        jsondata = json.dumps(response_data)
        return HttpResponse(jsondata)


return render(request, 'bill/invoicing.html')
```

Comment: You need to show some code.

Comment: Well, I am adding them in the edit. However, as its a little general, please note that the code would be "tiringly" long :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Model Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/) to output to the user a form to fill and create an object after submit. You can also use some context data if you need to pre-fill some informations in the form.

Another way is to just create an object and flag it as "CANCELLED" if you want to remember some user's tries (what can be useful sometimes) or just remove it (what can cause performance issues if it is very common situation to not fill started bill).

Comment: I am adding the code to explain why I am not using model forms. Could you kindly elaborate a little on flagging and removing objects, Thank You